# Custom directive 'A' angular js not working in grails gsp

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('appTooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.tooltip();
        }
    }});
```

and gsp:

```
<button appTooltip class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on left">test</button>
```

the directive 'A' does not work but if I use the directive 'C', it works. Why?

Comment: `appTooltip` should be `app-tooltip` when you specify in the html... camel casing is separated by `-`